# Virtualbox guest additions installation for Debian 9.2.1

Tags: virtualbox, debian, guest-additions

I have installed debian 9.2.1 in virtual box but now i want to install it in guest addition but i'm having problem .
Advice is needed.

TIA

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please add details about your problem by posting screenshots, steps you've already taken, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently known problems with guest additions on Debian guests, Oracle knows about it, and are working on a fix:

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=85132

(There are more threads about it on the Virtualbox forums).